# Can we create a feature for the changes in webform by using feature module?

Tags: webforms, features

I am unable to create a feature for the changes in webform on development site to be used on production site by using feature module.Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2):

Features does not give you the power to import/export the webform created.

You could use the [Webform Share](http://drupal.org/project/webform_share) module.

For more details you could read the README.txt file of this module.

Comment: Yes I used that module to export my weform already. Anyways thanks for the answer. My next question is I changed a menu link title in a menu apart from main menu, can I export changes using feature.I am unable to do that by feature so I used menu import/export module. Is that correct way or it can be done through feature ?